# my server hp dl 380gs:no display and very noise

Tags: hp

Recently I brought HP-DL380GS and I installed Windows 2008 with updates and left it a long time without use. Now the server does not display anything on the screen and occurs very loud noise?! .

What it his problem?

Comment: That's a DL380 G5, not "GS". What sort of "loud noise"?? Like a beeping noise or just the fans running? That is a loud server, it was meant to be reliable, not quiet.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention that you left it alone for a very long time, try reinserting the memory modules in the server. If there a lot of dust inside the server try removing that too. Dustin in the fan and smps can make things very noisy.  If you have RPS(Reduntant Pwoer supply module) see if both of them are connected to the power sockets.